# ">", "<", ">=" and "<=" don't work with "filter()" in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-filter, inequality

With `=` below, I could filter persons by `age`:

```py
qs = Person.objects.filter(age = 20)
                             # ↑ Here
```

But with `>`, `<`, `>=` and `<=` below, I couldn't filter persons by `age`:

```py
qs = Person.objects.filter(age > 20)
                             # ↑ Here
```

```py
qs = Person.objects.filter(age < 20)
                             # ↑ Here
```

```py
qs = Person.objects.filter(age >= 20)
                             # ↑↑ Here
```

```py
qs = Person.objects.filter(age <= 20)
                             # ↑↑ Here
```

Then, I got the error below:

> NameError: name 'age' is not defined

How can I do `greater than(>)`, `greater than or equal to(>=)`, `less than(<)` and `less than or equal to(>=)` with [filter()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter) in Django?

Comment: @BéresBotond Although the docs look great - the structuring and layout is so poor that without a direct link, they are all but useless

Comment: @BéresBotond Unfortunately that link is now dead :(

Comment: Working link for doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#gt

Answer (score 522, accepted):

Greater than:

```
Person.objects.filter(age__gt=20)
```

Greater than or equal to:

```
Person.objects.filter(age__gte=20)
```

Less than:

```
Person.objects.filter(age__lt=20)
```

Less than or equal to:

```
Person.objects.filter(age__lte=20)
```

You can find them all in [the documentation].(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/).

Comment: Wow, that was fast :). This works great for less than or equal, but how about just less than? (userprofile__level__lt=3) doesn't seem to work

Comment: It does; but in any case, you can also do exclude(__gte) instead of filter(__lt).

Comment: And do NOT forget that there are two `__` underlines

Comment: Im getting this error--> {FieldError}Unsupported lookup 'level' for AutoField or join on the field not permitted.

Comment: question, what does =0 mean here? false? true?

Comment: Remember change `userprofile__level` by your fields e.g. `youtfield__lte`. @AravindRPillai

Answer (score 1):

Put [__gt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#gt) suffix for "**G**reater **T**han" to **the field name `age`**:

```py
Person.objects.filter(age__gt=20)
                    #    ↑↑↑↑ 
                    # age > 20
```

Put [__gte](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#gte) suffix for "**G**reater **T**han or **E**qual to" to **the field name `age`**:

```py
Person.objects.filter(age__gte=20)
                    #    ↑↑↑↑↑ 
                    # age >= 20
```

Put [__lt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#lt) suffix for "**L**ess **T**han" to **the field name `age`**:

```py
Person.objects.filter(age__lt=20)
                    #    ↑↑↑↑ 
                    # age < 20
```

Put [__lte](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#lte) suffix for "**L**ess **T**han or **E**qual to" to **the field name `age`**:

```py
Person.objects.filter(age__lte=20)
                    #    ↑↑↑↑↑ 
                    # age <= 20
```