# Django working with date

Tags: python, django, date

I am building a site in the new pbs bento, and am being forced to use django for this instance, which I am not familiar with. Here is what I have:

```
    {% load sekizai_tags filertags %}
    {% with "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p" as the_time %}
    {% if the_time_gteitem01.date %}
    ..............
    {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
```

`item01.date` is declared elsewhere, and I am for sure that it works fine.

My question is am I doing this right?
I am trying to get the current date and place it in `the_time`. Then I am checking to see if `the_time` is greater or equal to `item01.date`, `{% if the_time_gteitem01.date %}`. Then I have some html that happens if it is true. Is gte greater than or equal to?
Sorry if I sound like a noob to this, but have never used django or python, and have gotten all my django knowledge from other examples.
Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation. I don't know why you expected this to work at all.

Comment: I would have, but have limited time and just need it for this one situation.

Answer (score 0):

No.

How would the_time become a date? You've declared it as a string.

And what makes you think you do comparisons in templates by appending "gte" and the value to compare? You don't at all.

Assuming that item01.date is an actual date object, you need to pass a variable (called eg `today`) containing `datetime.date.today()` from the view, then do a simple comparison:

```
{% if today > item01.date %}
```

Comment: Sorry, this is what I was looking at for date https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags, and this was what I was looking at for greater than or equal to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040143/how-to-do-a-less-than-or-equal-to-filter-in-django-queryset.   Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: It says, "Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'datetime.date.today()'" I am using this line of code  {% with today=datetime.date.today() %}

Comment: You can't do that in the template. You need to send the variable from the view.

Comment: I don't have access to the view. Bento doesn't allow us access to access their files in their server at all. Only stuff we upload