# How to query a row based on a variable that is within the range of 2 fields in my model

Tags: python, django

I want query a row where my variable is within the range of 2 fields in my model.

Supposed I have x = 100
Model = Product with 3 fields price_start, price_end, category.

I want to know which category is my 'x' variable.

How can i query this in django?

p.s. this is just a simplified example of my problem. 
Supposing price_start and price_end does not overlap, how to know the category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for ORM try this

```
x = yourModel.objects.filter(start_price__level__lte= "number",price_end__level__gte"number")
```

so x will be queryset of model

you can see in this post

Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040143/how-to-do-a-less-than-or-equal-to-filter-in-django-queryset)!

Comment: Can you tell me what does __level__ do here? its not in the example in docs. is this for older version? i use latest version of django. Sorry if noob question..

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this using **[gte](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#gte)** and **[lte](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#lte)**:

```
products = Product.objects.filter(price_start__gte=x, price_end__lte=x)

for product in products:
    print(product.category)

# Or

products.values_list('category')
```

Comment: so...it is not returning a query when done this way. It works when start and end of range are the same field tho like if price__gte=10,price__lte=20.

Comment: nope, it should work just fine :) . Please ensure to have price_start greater than x and price_end less than x.